# javascript calculates onload instead of onclick

Tags: javascript

I'm working on this program from Murach's javascript in ch 4 that calculates the future value of an investment after a certain amount of years and at a certain rate. The user inputs investment, years and rate, then clicks a button.

My problem:
The function calculate seems to run onload instead of waiting for the user to input information and click the button. I've followed the instructions in the book and they even give the answer to this program in the following chapter (ch.5). The same program in the next chapter runs, well. The only difference is that the program from before in ch.5 has data validation and the one in ch.4 doesn't. One of the exercises is to write the program without data validation.

I feel like it's just something really simple that I have overlooked.

I've searched up other ways to do the same thing, but I would really like to fix what I have with the window.onload function while attaching the event handler.

Here is what I have:

```js
"use strict"
var $ = function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
};

var calculateFV = function(investment,rate,years) {
 var futureValue = investment;
 for (var i = 1; i <= years; i++ ) {
  futureValue = futureValue + (futureValue * rate / 100);
 }
 futureValue = futureValue.toFixed(2);
 return futureValue;
};

var processEntries = function() {
 var investment = parseFloat( $("investment").value );
 var rate = parseFloat( $("rate").value );
 var years = parseInt( $("years").value );
 $("future_value").value = calculateFV(investment,rate,years);
};

window.onload = function() {
 $("calculate").onclick = processEntries();
 $("investment").focus();
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Future Value Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="future_value.css">
    <script src="future_value.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <h1>Future Value Calculator</h1>
        
        <label for="investment">Total Investment:</label>
        <input type="text" id="investment"><br>
        
        <label for="rate">Annual Interest Rate:</label>
        <input type="text" id="rate">%<br>
        
        <label for="years">Number of Years:</label>
        <input type="text" id="years"><br>
        
        <label for="future_value">Future Value:</label>
        <input type="text" id="future_value" disabled><br>
        
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate"><br>      
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: because you call it and assign what it returns to the event handler....

Comment: and a very bad idea to use `var $`

Comment: Thank you. Why is it bad to use var $ ? The book is very consistent about this. What is your take?

Comment: The variable name `$` may collide with some other libraries you may/will be using, especially JQuery. @ElizabethC

Answer (score 1):

You're invoking the `processEntries` function here

```
 $("calculate").onclick = processEntries();
```

and setting it to `click` event. It should be like this to work

```
$("calculate").onclick = processEntries;
```

And using `$` might cause you a lot of trouble in the future if your code gets longer then you use a lot of `$` and you include to `jQuery` in your project.